# Issue with rotation in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm trying to Rotate my GameObject using the script around Y axis:

```
    rotateDir = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    rb.AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.up * rotateDir * rotateForce);
```

But my GameObject starting tilt (last picture):

[image]
[image]

I have changed colliders, checked my code (I can't see any errors)< but still it doesn't work properly. Could anybody help me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Update()
    {
        RotateTowardsYDirection();
    }

    public void RotateTowardsYDirection()
    {
        ////transform object to rotate with some rotation factor value
        objectToRotate.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * yRotationFactor * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to rotate gameObject in unity. But the best way to rotate is using EularAngles

```
// Transform.eulerAngles represents rotation in world space
void Update() {
  currentEulerAngles += new Vector3(x, y, z) * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed;

  //apply the change to the gameObject
  transform.eulerAngles = currentEulerAngles;
}
```

Comment: No, it is not! From [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) `When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.`

Comment: Besides that OP already shows us how they rotate the object ... the question is not how to rotate but about the issue that occurs in OP's rotation

Comment: @derHugo What mean "OP"?